# Why bufferTime(5000, 10000) shows values that I created after 5000ms

Tags: rxjs

Code:

```
const source = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document.getElementById('click'), 'click')
const example = source.bufferTime(5000,10000);
const subscribe = example.subscribe(val => console.log('Start Buffer Every 1s:', val));
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/whity/9gbpf8uz/3/)

I don't understand two things:

1. Why first value is returned after 5s not 10s
2. After 10s (as soon as I see empty array in console) I start clicking btn. I do it for 4 seconds, and after 10s there is still empty array. But if I start clicking after 5 seconds since the appearance of an empty array in the console, there is a proper result.

I thought that it will work like "Every 10 seconds, emit the click events from the next 5 seconds". But it doesn't.

Comment: What does the [documentation](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/bufferTime) say about it?

Comment: Igor, I read it but don't get it. Sorry, I'm still learning. I got impression that it works differently that in documentation. "If bufferCreationInterval is given, this operator opens the buffer every bufferCreationInterval milliseconds and closes (emits and resets) the buffer every bufferTimeSpan milliseconds." But the value is visible after 10s not 5s (bufferTimeSpan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
bufferTime(bufferTimeSpan: number, bufferCreationInterval: number, ..)
// bufferTimeSpan: The amount of time to fill each buffer array.
// bufferCreationInterval: The interval at which to start new buffers.
```

#### bufferTimeSpan < bufferCreationInterval ⟹ gaps between buffer intervals

```js
Example 1: bufferTimer(5000, 10000)

// 1. bufferCreationInterval = 10000
//    open the buffer every 10 seconds, start with an open buffer

                      ┌ 5   ┌ 10  ┌ 15  ┌ 20  ┌ 25  ┌ 30  ┌ 35  ┌ 40  ┌ 45  ┌ 50

bufferInterval: [----- -----[----- -----[----- -----[----- -----[----- -----[---


// 2. bufferTimeSpan = 5000
//    close the buffer 5 seconds after it was opened

                      ┌ 5   ┌ 10  ┌ 15  ┌ 20  ┌ 25  ┌ 30  ┌ 35  ┌ 40  ┌ 45  ┌ 50

bufferInterval: [~~~~~]-----[~~~~~]-----[~~~~~]-----[~~~~~]-----[~~~~~]-----[~~~
```

> As soon as I see empty array in console I start clicking button, I do
>   it for 4 seconds.

```js
                       ┌┬┬┬ sounds like you click here, nothing is recorded      
                       ││││        
bufferInterval: [~~~~~]-----[~~~~~]-----[~~~~~]-----[~~~~~]-----[~~~~~]-----[~~~
```

> If I start clicking after 5 seconds since the appearance of an empty
>   array in the console, there is a proper result.

```js
                             ┌┬┬┬ sounds like you click here, values are buffered
                             ││││        
bufferInterval: [~~~~~]-----[~~~~~]-----[~~~~~]-----[~~~~~]-----[~~~~~]-----[~~~
```

---

#### bufferTimeSpan > bufferCreationInterval ⟹ overlapping buffer intervals

```js
Example 2: bufferTimer(2000, 1000)

// 1. bufferCreationInterval = 1000
//    open the buffer every 1 seconds, start with an open buffer

                               ┌ 5            ┌ 10           ┌ 15           ┌ 20

bufferInterval: (- [- {- (- [- {- (- [- {- (- [- {- (- [- {- (- [- {- (- [- {- (-


// 2. bufferTimeSpan = 2000
//    close the buffer 2 seconds after it was opened

                               ┌ 5            ┌ 10           ┌ 15           ┌ 20

bufferInterval: (~ [~){~](~}[~){~](~}[~){~](~}[~){~](~}[~){~](~}[~){~](~}[~){~](~}

// split into multiple layers for better view
layer1:         (~  ~) - (~  ~) - (~  ~) - (~  ~) - (~  ~) - (~  ~) - (~  ~) - (~
layer2:          - [~  ~] - [~  ~] - [~  ~] - [~  ~] - [~  ~] - [~  ~] - [~  ~] -
layer3:          -  - {~  ~} - {~  ~} - {~  ~} - {~  ~} - {~  ~} - {~  ~} - {~  ~}
```